Convert a list to a float variable
I write this code to read text from .docx file and put the numbers in to a list to calculate their sum. Now I need to convert list to a variable and calculate sum of them.
My code:
from docx import Document

num_list = []

doc = Document('File.docx')
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    for char in para.text:
        if char in '0123456789۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹.':
            num_list.append(char)
        else :
            if num_list != [] and num_list != ['.']  :
                print(num_list)
            num_list = []

Output:
['2', '.', '7']
['۳']
['۳', '۰', '۶']
['۷', '۴']
['۵']
['۹', '۰']
['۱', '۰']
['۱', '۵']
['۲', '۶']

I want to convert list to float variable and calculate sum:
['2', '.', '7'] --> 2.7


float(''.join(num_list))

But note that your code doesn't necessarily find numbers - there's no guarantee any of those characters are next to each other.

The usage of the word sum is quite confusing

You should consider using a regular expression to find actual numbers in the text and not just individual digits, that may or may not form a multi-digit number in a line. (Also, you do not consider negative numbers, not sure if that's relevant.)

You can use sum() with a generator expression to convert each number in the list to float utilizing str.join:
nums = [
    ['2', '.', '7'],
    ['۳'],
    ['۳', '۰', '۶'],
    ['۷', '۴'],
    ['۵'],
    ['۹', '۰'],
    ['۱', '۰'],
    ['۱', '۵'],
    ['۲', '۶'],
]

for num in nums:
  print(f'{num} =', float(''.join(num)))

total = sum(float(''.join(num)) for num in nums)
print(f'{total = }')

Output:
['2', '.', '7'] = 2.7
['۳'] = 3.0
['۳', '۰', '۶'] = 306.0
['۷', '۴'] = 74.0
['۵'] = 5.0
['۹', '۰'] = 90.0
['۱', '۰'] = 10.0
['۱', '۵'] = 15.0
['۲', '۶'] = 26.0
total = 531.7


Based on what you've provided, you're looking to:

Accumulate numbers (Persian and Arabic) from a .docx into a list
Sum that list and return a float

In addition to the solutions already suggested, this is another way to do it:
from docx import Document
import re

document = Document("File.docx")
text = " ".join(paragraph.text for paragraph in document.paragraphs)

# Find numbers, converting the Persian numbers to Arabic
persian_to_arabic = str.maketrans("۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹", "0123456789")
numbers = re.findall(pattern=r"-?\d+\.\d+|-?\d+|[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]+", string=text)
converted_numbers = [num.translate(persian_to_arabic) for num in numbers]

# Sum the list and return a float
total = sum(map(float, converted_numbers))
print(total)

Testing with the following input:
document = Document()
document.add_paragraph("The total cost is $45.67 and the discount is $5.50.")
document.add_paragraph("The Persian digits for 123 are ۱۲۳.")
document.add_paragraph("A negative number like -123.45 should be considered.")

This gives us ['45.67', '5.50', '123', '123', '-123.45'], which sums to 173.72000000000003.

Actually, int and float can handle persian numbers just fine, so the translate is not really necessary. Apart from that, I'd say this is the way to go. (Or translate first, so the regex is simpler, e.g. it seems you only allow decimal-point for the "regular" digits.)
